# iTextSharp NewPage issue after Landscape page

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

If a page has been placed into Landscape orientation, and that page ends up spanning multiple pages, and the next page is portrait the NewPage() call hangs and throws an out of memory error. Landscape works fine if it all fits on a single page, or if the following page is also landscape.

Below is the rectangle I use for the SetPageSize() call.

```
        public Rectangle PageLayout
    {
        get
        {
            if (PageOrientation == PageOrientation.Landscape)
                return PageSize.LETTER.Rotate();
            return PageSize.LETTER;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post a very simple but complete example that shows this so that we can reproduce it? Also, what version of iTextSharp are you using?

Comment: Version number is 5.4.1.0.   Will take me a couple hours to pull out enough code to create a sample that can be run.  I will try to get that compiled this evening.